# I want to remove the only the brackets {36774343-CC45-4693-8F3A-F4EBAB6BB3C6}

Tags: notepad++

Its late here and I'm having trouble just removing the '{' and '}' in one shot using Notepad++

I've searched and searched, the Syntax isn't making any sense to me at this hour, any help would be appreciated.

I have this:

```
{36774343-CC45-4693-8F3A-F4EBAB6BB3C6}
```

I  want this:

```
36774343-CC45-4693-8F3A-F4EBAB6BB3C6
```

I know I can run a couple replace but I am trying to save time, these are rather large files.

Comment: Hi, you should provide the `code` solutions you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove **all** curly brackets, use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[{}]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY` or a space if it's more convenient
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: @JamesBryan: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)